# How to handle SSL error using self-signed certificate in Xamarin.Forms Webview?

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin.forms

How to handle SSL error using self-signed certificate in Xamarin.Forms Webview? It is just showing a blank white page. I have searched the web and almost all solutions use Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS. Help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer my code posted on GitHub: [Handle SSL error in xamarin.Forms webview](https://gist.github.com/MansiShah04/2638427748d11f69aee85d22010e1f91)

Hope this may solve your issue.